# How to exit codeigniter without die() in __construct() function of controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a controller where in the constructor function, I want to check if the user is logged in or not. If not, I want an error message to be displayed, and for the script to exit without running any other function in the controller. This controller will only be called by ajax so the error would be displayed via JSON and then the javascript on the client will display it to the user.

How can I do this? If I did this:

```
function __construct()
{
   if (! $this->loggedIn() )
   {
      echo json_encode( array('error'=> true) );
      die;
   }    
}
```

I don't think the message would be displayed because codeigniter uses output buffering. Any ideas?

Comment: @xdazz I did try it, and die works, however I remember in the past I had trouble echoing and just die()ing, so I'd like a definite answer from someone knowledgeable.

Comment: The definite answer is that this works. I don't know the reason why wouldn't it.

Comment: Either way, this is terrible for usability. Why not just output into a template with a login form as well?

Comment: you can actually call [`ob_end_flush`](http://php.net/ob_end_flush) before `die` to send the content of output buffer to browser...

Comment: but i'd imagine codeigniter should have some kind of error handlers to show an error template

Comment: You can also throw an Exception, not sure how CI will handle that though.

Comment: Its actually for an ajax only controller, the output will be in JSON rather than just a message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i understood that your problem is the client expects for a json type of response, so two options to use:

```
public function __construct(){

    $_bad_login_msg = 'please try again' ;
    parent::__construct();

    if(!userLoggedIn()){

        $this->output
        ->set_content_type('application/json')
        ->set_output(json_encode($_bad_login_msg));

        //or just use 
        //     echo json_encode($_bad_login_msg);
        die;
    }
}
```

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/output.html

you won't have any buffering problems, the buffer contents will be sent to the client **after** the die...

Answer (score 4):

The best way is to redirect the user to login page. 
As mentioned here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/10399199/876117

```
public function __construct(){
  parent::__construct();
  if(!userLoggedIn())
    $this->load->view('promptlogin');
    $this->output->_display();
    exit();

}

public function index(){
  // one will never reach here unless he is logged in
  $this->load->view('actualcontent');
}
```

Comment: this isn't what i asked for. I need to output a message in the same controller.

Comment: well in that case you can load a different views for different case. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can just use something like this:

```
function __construct()
{
   if (! $this->loggedIn() )
   {
     exit('Please login before visiting this page');
   }    
}
```

Comment: This is kinda same as what OP posted... he mentioned he didn't want to call `die`

Comment: They're function aliases, therefore it's equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

MY_Controller is your top level/parent controller so its all done in there because every other controller will extend it.  So if you have an auth controller(which extends MY_Controller) you will have access to its logic.

**So MY_Controller**

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller{

    protected $_user;

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

        $this->_user = $this->session->userdata('uid')
                     ? find_a_user : NULL;
        // if a session of user_id exists and is found in DB
        // we have a live user
    }
}
```

**Auth**

```
class Auth extends MY_Controller{
   public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        // we now have access to $this->_user

        if($this->_user !== NULL)  // we have active user
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you should use [flashdata](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html) and redirect to a controller with it. Then you can control if any flashdata comes in session, after that write it in view.